# How to set target with event.target name element?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I use UI dialog for a Ajax form.
UI dialog must appear with clicking on two to six link with different ID.
After submitting form and hiding the UI Dialog, Ajax return and replace submitted row from database to place of clicked link.
My script is not working.
Is it possible to do this function with jQuery?
This is my default function for one link:

```
$('#add').ajaxForm({
 target: '#start',
 success: function() {
  $('#start').fadeIn('slow');
 });
```

and this is my idea! for multiple link:

```
$('#add').ajaxForm({
 var xx = '#'+$(event.target.name);
 target: xx,
 success: function() {
  $(xx).fadeIn('slow');
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For that to work you need the **event** object ..

You are trying to access the event object inside a method which is not possible.

If you call that in a method it won't make any sense..